# Add [spoilers] Tag to Questions When Answering

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, answers, spoilers

When someone asks a question on Gaming, they may tag it as [spoilers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers) to warn other people off.  However, what if the **answer** to a question contains spoilers?  For example, [This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/how-do-i-unlock-the-ilomilo-shuffle) of my own (this may not be the **best** example, but it was easy to find).  Upon receiving the answer, I retagged the question, but there still exists a gap of time in between the answer being posted, and the op retagging the question.  And this is, of course, assuming that the op is a regular user who returns to retag it.

Yes, I'm aware that the answerer blanked out his spoilers, but even still, I think the question should have the tag if the page contains any spoilers at all.

---

So, I was thinking, what if users were given the option to add the [spoilers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers) tag to any question they answer?  I was thinking of a simple checkbox, that asks something like, "Does this post contain spoilers?", or "Will this post create spoilers on the page?".  Obviously, there would have to be a rep requirement for this ability.

Answer (score 6):

-9,001. Use the `>!` syntax to mark spoilers. If the title doesn't contain spoilers remove that tag.

Comment: Ouch.  Harsh, guy.

Comment: I thought the opposite of over9000 was 1006